# Rotate and replace fab icon in android

Tags: android

I have a fab button with camera icon (defined in xml)
I want on click to rotate the icon and replace it by x...

I am using the following xml to make a rotation

Thank you[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that using ObjectAnimator, here:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(fab, "rotation", 0f, 360f).setDuration(800).start();
            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (isWhite){
                        fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_black_48dp));
                        isWhite = false;
                    } else {
                        fab.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_add_white_48dp));
                        isWhite = true;
                    }
                }
            }, 400);
        }
    });
```

Icon will change in the middle of rotation

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for animating vector drawables. It will provide you a morphing effect which is awesome ;)

It is a bit complicated but you can read more about it here:

https://lewismcgeary.github.io/posts/animated-vector-drawable-pathMorphing/

and here is useful tool:

https://github.com/bonnyfone/vectalign

[image: PathMorphing Android <-> iOS]